# System.Threading.Tasks conflicts in MathNet.Numerics and Parse

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, parse-platform

I am developing a Unity project where i need to use both [MathNet.Numerics](https://mathnetnumerics.codeplex.com/) and [Parse](https://parse.com/). The problem is that they both need to access System.Threading, but since Unity only allows 3.5, they both ship their own. Parse have, however, embedded the part they need into the Parse-dll, but the missing some parts (System.Collections.Concurrent) that MathNet.Numerics needs. This means it cannot be used by MathNet. I can not add both to the Unity project since the System.Threading needed by MathNet.Numerics conflicts with the namespace embedded into the Parse.Unity.dll.

I have no idea how to solve this. Anyone tried something similair?

Comment: I hope I'm not misleading you, but unless you have the actual source code  I don't think there's much you can do

Comment: This is what i am fearing!

Comment: Perhaps [alias directives](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664765%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) could help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MathNet requires .NET 4.0 or newer and Parse only supports .NET 4.5 or newer, Unity only supports .NET 3.5.

For the math portion you will need to find a library that targets 3.5 if you want to use it in a Unity project, the only way to make MathNet work for 3.5 is if you re-wrote the source code to not use any 4.0 or newer features (not a easy task).

For Parse, you will need to find a different library that provides the same features. There source for Parse is not available so you would not be able to re-write it.